# Подключение на локальном сервере к html файлу js файлов

Tags: javascript, express, localhost

Возникла проблема:
**Refused to execute script from 'http://192.168.30.91:3000/base.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.**
Как исправить?
У меня есть:

\mainproject

- base.js
- index.html
- index.js`

`index.js` отвечает за создание сервера с помощью `http`, `express`, `socket.io`. `index.html` - главный файл. `base.js` - вспомогательный js файл. В `index.js` для подключения к серверу `index.html` и `base.js` написал:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "js")));
app.get('/', function(request, respons) {
    respons.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

В `index.html` для подключения `base.js` написал:
`<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/base.js"></script>`
НО ничего не помогает, выводит ошибку, указанную выше. Что делать? Перепробовал другие способы из интернета, тоже не помогли.

Comment: Попробуйте создать каталог js и в него положить ваш base.js